# Alternate approach to block incoming requests until some initialization ends in ASP.NET and avoiding deadlocks

Tags: asp.net, .net, initialization, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

Some class requires to initialize some application-wide resource only when some of the methods within the class it's invoked within an HTTP request.

In addition, initialization occurs requesting some data from some HTTP/REST service. Furthermore, the service resource is requested asynchronously with the async pattern (`async`/`await`).

For now, I've been blocking all requests until the initialization ends using a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and `TryEnterWriteLock` with a predefined timeout.

My problem is that sometimes `TryEnterWriteLock` ends in a deadlock, even if there's no write lock held.

My assumption is that it's not guaranteed that, once some *awaitable* ends its asynhcronous operation, the blocked code continues in the same thread because of how threading and `SynhcronizationContext` works on ASP.NET, meaning that the write lock is never exited.

Perhaps I could move the whole code to the Global.asax `Application_Start` event handler, but the point is I don't want to initialize the whole resource once per application life-cycle, because the requested resource has expiration and it may be requested again overtime.

### The whole question...

**What would be the right approach to this situation where there's asynhcronous code and other incoming HTTP requests should wait until the request who owns the asynchronous *awaitable* initialization without ending in the so-called deadlock?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the solution is right in front of you, but you're just blinded!

Blocking all incoming requests until the resource has been acquired? Why? Wrong, wrong, Wrong!

There's an approach called *cache* and a known API called ASP.NET Cache, and there's a method `Cache.Insert` accepting a *cache update callback* being invoked overtime by a given time interval...

- [Cache.Insert(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491414.aspx)
- [Some old MSDN article about this topic.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2008/07/22/asp-net-cache-can-notify-you-before-an-entry-is-removed.aspx)

Again: don't block, don't block!

The so-called cache update callback runs in a separate thread. It's just about configuring the cache update just some time before it expires and no request will be blocked: users and machines will continue their work without interruptions!

Oh, and the `Cache.Insert(...)` should be called in the `Application_Start` event handler in the `Global.asax` class.

I hope both my question and answer will be useful as an advise for others in order to avoid bad threading/blocking practices...

Comment: I've tried this approach myself in the actual ASP.NET app, and it works like a charm! I found a good approach, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

- leverage the `Lazy<>` object (you haven't told us if the resource is "single" (a file for example), if it's per user, or if it's something like a dictionary where each possible key/value must be loaded lazily.
- There is the [ConfigureAwait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx) method...

> MyObject result = await task.ConfigureAwait(true)

now result will be returned on the original thread. If you make the locks in the same method, the locks will be freed correctly

Comment: Well, the whole resource is for all requests, thus, all users too. About `Lazy<T>`, you're right, it's a possible solution. About the `ConfigureAwait(true)`, AFAIK this won't work well in ASP.NET because of how it work IIS thread pool, you know.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer There is this cycle of articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10267069.aspx here it speaks of how to build an `AsyncReaderWriterLock` (I haven't ever tested it). They are built for `async`

Comment: There is even this: http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/ , its [AsyncReaderWriterLock](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncReaderWriterLock&referringTitle=Documentation) is based on the article I told you before.

Comment: Have you read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx and are you using `<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer And I hope you aren't using `Task.Wait`... There seem to be some subtle problems in ASP.NET that can cause deadlocks, see http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/the-perfect-recipe-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-ending-up-with-a-deadlock-using-the-c-sharp-5-0-asynchronous-language-features and http://code.jonwagner.com/2012/09/04/deadlock-asyncawait-is-not-task-wait/ for example

Comment: I was using them and then I found a lot of articles about *using await all the way* :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer sadly `async`/`await` are *very* complex constructs. They hide too much, and knowing how every piece will combine with the others is a science in itself.

Comment: BTW, `Lazy<T>` won't work in this scenario. Remember that the initialization may occurs many times during application life-cycle.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer In your question you spoke of application-wide resource... singular. You could use a `ConcurrentDictionary` for application-wide resource**s**

Comment: The problem isn't the access to a synchronized resource. It's about querying a RESTful service, receive the result and then resume the incoming requests from other users.

Comment: I've not tested any solution yet apart of the deadlocking one, but after thinking about it, I've arrived to some conclusion and I'm pretty sure it's, maybe, the best approach. I'm going to answer my own question!

Answer (score 1):

I have an [entry on my blog that deals with "asynchronous construction"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). I prefer the "async factory" approach, but that sounds like it won't fit your situation because your resource is shared app-wide.

In that case, I recommend `AsyncLazy<T>`, which is just a `Lazy<T>` that is `async`-enabled (i.e., the factory method can be `async`, and consumers can `await` for the initialization to complete). `AsyncLazy<T>` is a good match if your resource is exposed as a static property.

If you're using DI/IoC, however, you really do need to have (synchronous) construction (at least until the DI/IoC libraries support some form of asynchronous construction). In that case, you can use the "asynchronous initialization" code pattern.

Alternatively, you *could* use an `AsyncReaderWriterLock` that I developed as part of my [`AsyncEx` library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/). But I think the other approaches are more clear in their intent.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for adding your suggestions and comments about solving the problem. As you stated in your answer, it seems that the cache approach will work better in my scenario, but I Feel that all answers are very valid for future visitors with similar problems.